# HTTPS with a self signed certificate!

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I am using a Self signed certificate for HTTPS. I have it ready. Could someone please tell me what should be changed in IIS and also what should be changed in the code for https to come into affect. I need https for some pages(not all).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to the site and change the properties so it is on port 443.  In IIS 7, you do this where you add host headers to the site.  It's been a while since I've used IIS 6 so I can't tell you off the top of my head.  Once that is done, try visiting the site and change http to https.

If it doesn't show the page, make sure port 443 is open on the machine firewall (it should be by default).  If your code is not auto forcing https, you can use IIS redirection rules to auto force https on the pages that need it.

Comment: You mean, change the TCP or SSL?? I am new to this. and please don't mind if i am asking something minimal. Every letter you write is very much to me. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add a host header to your site, when you do, pick HTTPS and port 443.  Once you have the host header added you should be able to hit the site on either http or https.  Then, through IIS, you should be able to set up redirection rules for the pages you want protected.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have Multiple identities for this website with port 80 pointing to website url. And i have Multiple SSL identities for the website set with address and the port 443.

Comment: I am sorry it has not worked! I dont know if i am missing something!

Comment: you should only have one https host header per ip on the machine.  You can have multiple host headers on port 80, you just have to give each one a different subdomain name.  Https does not let you put in a subdomain name with the host header.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS6 you need to enable port 443 for the site, through "Directory Security > Server Certificate..." and follow the wizard to import your certificate.

Comment: the certificate is currently installed on the website. :) What is next? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/56bdf977-14f8-4867-9c51-34c346d48b04.mspx?mfr=true